# Define getter/setter on existing object w/ TypeScript

Tags: typescript, properties, typescript2.0

How would I write the following code using TypeScript?

```
document.__defineGetter__('cookie', function() { ... });
document.__defineSetter__('cookie', function(v) { ... });
```

Thanks in advance!

(p.s. this assumes `document` exists, but `document.cookie` does not... )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **Object.defineProperty** in order to do so.

You'll also have to amend the existing's object interface so the compiler knows you added it too.

```js
interface Document {
    cake: string
}

Object.defineProperty(document, 'cake', {
    get: function () {
        return this.id + 'a';
    },
    set: function (value) {
        this.id = value;
    }
});


console.log(document.cake);

document.cake = 'abc';

console.log(document.cake);
```

You can see a working example [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%0D%0Ainterface%20Document%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20cake%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AObject.defineProperty(document%2C%20'cake'%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20get%3A%20function%20()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.id%20%2B%20'a'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20set%3A%20function%20(value)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.id%20%3D%20value%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(document.cake)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Adocument.cake%20%3D%20'abc'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(document.cake)%3B%0D%0A).